# Call one function from another

Tags: ractivejs

I have a custom function according to [documentation](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/expressions). What documentation doesn't cover (or I'm blind) is how to call one function from another. Here is what I tried:

```
var myRactive = new Ractive({
    el: '#element',
    template: '#template',
    data: {
        function1: function() {
            return 100;
        },
        function2: function() {
            return function1() / 2;
        }
    }
});
```

It doesn't work. I tried to change it to `myRactive.function1()`, `myRactive.data.function1()`, etc. but neither of them worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `this.get('function1')` to get it from your data object, then run it as a function like this.

```
var myRactive = new Ractive({
el: 'body',
template: '#ele',
data: {
    function1: function() {
        return 100;
    },
    function2: function() {
        return this.get('function1')() / 2;
    }
}
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gs3yhhsz/1/

In pre 0.7 ractive, you could access the data-object directly (`this.data`). This got changed, and you should now use `this.get()` and `this.set()` instead.